# Taking Head of function in operator form (and manipulating arguments in operator form)

Tags: functions, function-construction, expression-manipulation

Is there a simple function that will take expressions of the form

```
f[a1][a2][a3]
```

and will output `f`, for an arbitrary number of arguments `a1`, `a2`, a3, etc (also possibly zero).

Also, is there a simple function to rearrange the input to `f[a1, a2, a3]` (which of course would immediately solve the first question too).

---

My own attempt for the first problem:

```
takeHead[expr_] := FixedPointList[Head, expr][[-3]]
```

which seems to work but I don't know whether it is robust for all cases. (We can optionally add a `HoldAll` depending of whether we want to take the head before or after evaluation.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively:

```
NestWhile[Head, f[a1][a2][a3], MatchQ[_[___]]]
```

> ```
> f
> ```

```
NestWhile[
  Join[#[[0]], #[[0, 0]] @@ #] &
, f[a1][a2][a3]
, MatchQ[_[___][___]]
]
```

> ```
> f[a1, a2, a3]
> ```

Answer (score 4):

Your expression is composed of three nested functions. At the outermost level, `f[a1][a2]` is the Head to `a3`:

```
expr = f[a1][a2][a3];
{expr[[0]], expr[[1]]}

(* {f[a1][a2], a3} *)
```

As you suggested, you will get to the innermost Head, `f`, by applying the `Head` function until the result no longer changes. An elegant way to do it is to replace any function definition by its Head with `ReplaceRepeated`:

```
ReplaceRepeated[f[a1][a2][a3], h_[___] :> h]
(* f *)
```

For the second part of the question, just a quick and dirty solution with Sow and Reap:

```
Reap[
  ReplaceRepeated[f[a1][a2][a3], 
     h_[e___] :> (Sow[{e}]; h)]
] /. {func_, {arguments_}} :> func[Sequence @@ Join @@ Reverse[arguments]]
```

Note the braces around the argument `e` in `Sow` to support multiple arguments. `Join` then neutralizes this before `Sequence`ing the arguments together.

**EDIT**

And now the proper solution, kindly provided by the documentation of [ref/ReplaceRepeated](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceRepeated.html):

```
ReplaceRepeated[f[a1][a2][a3], h_[a___][b___] -> h[a, b]]
(* f[a1, a2, a3] *)
```

Comment: An equivalent (I think!) way to do this is:

`expr//.g_[_]->g`

right? actually, that's obvious after the fact :)

Comment: Yes, `//.` is the shorthand code for `ReplaceRepeated`. Note that `g_[x_]` specifies exactly one argument, so it will not match `f[a1][a2,a3,a4]` or `f[a1][]`.

Comment: May I ask if there's an advantage to using `:>` instead of `->` in this context?

Comment: Indeed it does not make a difference here.

Answer (score 2):

A couple other ideas to extract the head:

```
expr = f[a][b][c];

FirstCase[expr, _, Missing[], {-1}, Heads->True]
First @ Level[expr, {-1}, Heads->True]
```

> f
>
> f

Answer (score 1):

A very naïve—but I think slightly faster—solution to the second part of your question may be to use strings, if your arguments do really look like you've proposed.

On my test expression, which is `f` followed by the alphabet 10 times:

```
expr=Fold[#1@#2 &, f, ToExpression /@ Flatten[Table[Alphabet[], 10]]];
```

I can just use `ToString` and `StringReplace` to take advantage of the repetitive structure:

```
ToExpression@StringReplace[ToString@expr, "][" -> ","]
```

This is about 2.5x as fast on my machine; they seem to equalize as the number of arguments increases. For short sequences of arguments, this seems faster—and is also a little easier to understand, perhaps! Theo's solution is certainly more general, but this might work for what you need.

EDIT: This does remain a little faster than the new—and very clean!— `ReplaceRepeated` solution, it seems.