# Possible bug ParallelDo (or better practices for ParallelDo)

Tags: parallelization

`ParallelDo` is having problems evaluate an expression that evaluates fine outside `ParallelDo`. The problem is not due to the use of functions with side effects because I managed to trace the problem to the following very simple parallelizable task.

If I define the following function that takes arguments with a certain `Head` (the last `Head` before symbol to be precise, see [Taking Head of function in operator form (and manipulating arguments in operator form)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/171230/taking-head-of-function-in-operator-form-and-manipulating-arguments-in-operator)).

```
tstToString[expr_?(FixedPointList[Head,#][[-3]]===bla&)]:=ToString[expr];
```

This works fine in ParallelDo, however if I define

```
tstToString2[expr_?(head[#]===bla&)]:=ToString[expr];
```

and the function

```
head[expr_]:=FixedPointList[Head,expr][[-3]]
```

then `tstToString2` works fine outside `ParallelDo`, but not within it. In `ParallelDo` it will always leave `tstToString2[bla[stuff][stuff]]` unevaluated.
For example:

```
ParallelDo[Print[tstToString[bla[{f, pe, 0}][1][1, 0]]<>"b"],{vv,0,0}]
```

will give an error for `StringJoin` since the first expression will still not be a string.

How do I reliably write code that works the same in `ParallelDo`, when something as simple as this can screw it up. Are there some general practices that I am missing?

(The point is not to find a work around here, but to find some guiding principles for what screws things up. Otherwise I am afraid I cannot reliably work with ``.)

---

The answer might be version dependent because it occurs for 11.1.1 for Linux x86 that is used on a cluster I use but not on my own machine running 11.3.0 for Linux x86.

Comment: `DistributeDefinitions` ?

Comment: @user6014, but why specifically would i have to distribtute this definition by hand and not others. What is the logic behind that? It seems completely random. All functions are defined in the same way (same context) as far as I can tell. So I either expect them all to automatically be distributed or none of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that this is due to a bug that existed prior to version 11.3.0. In later versions ParellelDo behaves as expected.